# Existe alguma forma de otimizar um if em Java?

Tags: java

Eu gostaria de saber se há uma forma de otimizar(torná-lo mais rápido e legível) um if/else, fiz meio que um seletor para qual método você quer que execute, porém há muitos if's no código, o que me aparenta estar incorreto. o código é esse:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern; 

public class Lista4 {
    //Método para verificar se a palavra é um palíndromo
    public static void ex7() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String word, wordReverse = "";

        System.out.println("Escreva uma palavra: ");
        word = sc.next();

        for(int i = 0;i < word.length(); i++) {
            wordReverse = word.charAt(i) + wordReverse;
        }

        if (word.equals(wordReverse)) {
            System.out.println("Essa palavra é um palíndromo");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Essa palavra não é um palíndromo.");
        }

        sc.close();
    }

    //Main para iniciar os outros métodos
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String num;

        System.out.println("Escreva o número do exercício: ");
        num = sc.next();

        if (num.equals("1")) {
            ex1();
        } else if (num.equals("2")) {
            ex2();
        } else if (num.equals("3")) {
            ex3();
        } else if (num.equals("4")) {
            ex4();
        } else if (num.equals("5")) {
            ex5();
        } else if (num.equals("6")) {
            ex6();
        } else if (num.equals("7")) {
            ex7();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Comando não reconhecido");
        }

        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Ainda há os outros métodos que eu criei, mas decidi tirar pra ficar mais legível aqui na dúvida.

Comment: Não é por nada, mas para mim isso é o mais otimizado possível. Se você quiser tornar "legível", é outra coisa que não tem a ver com otimização. Otimizar é reduzir a quantia de instruções para realizar determinada tarefa, e nesse caso está bem otimizado já.

Comment: Defina "otimizar" para sabermos do que está falando.

Comment: Pra mim o código já está legível o suficiente, não tem o que inventar. Talvez em casos mais complexos justifique [usar outras alternativas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2086546). Teve uma resposta apagada que sugeriu que o `switch` fica mais rápido, o que até pode ser verdade em algumas situações, mas **na esmagadora maioria dos casos a diferença será irrisória e imperceptível**. As pessoas tem que parar de pensar nessas micro-otimizações: se quer otimizar performance, primeiro faça testes para descobrir os gargalos (e garanto que quase nunca a solução será trocar `if` por `switch`).

Comment: Acho que agora entendi melhor o conceito de otimização e legibilidade, obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Neste caso, eu não vejo algo para melhorar a performance. Se você deseja aprimorar a legibilidade do código, então vejo algumas opções; contudo, tenha em mente que legibilidade é relativa.

Uma alternativa é mudar para um switch (apenas em versões mais recentes do Java):

```java
switch (num) {
    case "1" -> ex1();
    case "2" -> ex2();
    case "3" -> ex3();
    case "4" -> ex4();
    case "5" -> ex5();
    case "6" -> ex6();
    case "7" -> ex7();
    default -> System.out.println("Comando não reconhecido");
}
```

Outra alternativa é usar um Map, no entanto, eu não acho melhor neste caso devido à complexidade extra do "default":

```java
Map<String, Runnable> execucoes = Map.of(
        "1", this::ex1,
        "2", this::ex2,
        "3", this::ex3,
        "4", this::ex4,
        "5", this::ex5,
        "6", this::ex6,
        "7", this::ex7
);

execucoes.getOrDefault(num, () -> System.out.println("Comando não reconhecido")).run();
```

Comment: Complementando, esta nova sintaxe do `switch` [vale a partir do Java 14](https://openjdk.org/jeps/361) (no Java 12 e 13 estava como [*preview*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/12), precisa habilitar explicitamente com a opção `--enable-preview `)